# When to use a web service and when not to use a web service?

Tags: web-services, architecture

When to use a web service and when not to use a web service?

Comment: Could you perhaps be more concise? What are you planning on programming?

Answer (score 3):

WebService is a way of interoperability between Heterogeneous and/or Homogeneous systems... Like many other mechanisms i.e. Sockets, RPC, Shared Resources etc....

Perhaps you should phrase your question as "What are the Advantages and Disadvantages of Web Services"

The one Disadvantage I list is "The amount of overhead... i.e. Noise... for some pplz it's meta data but depending upon the scenario it can be annoying".